# Can super() and this() appear in the same constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

I want to call both a parent constructor and another constructor in the same subclass. Is this allowed? Also, I understand that `this()` has some limitations on it (having to be placed first) does `super()`? Can I place a call to both in the same constructor?

Comment: I did try it, but I wanted to understand the rules behind it. I wanted to make sure I wasn't just getting lucky with something I tried, and that something similar would work as well. It can sometimes be hard to discern the whole picture from trying different combinations. I didn't mean to ask a bad question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the same class, yes.

```
class Stuff extends Object
{
      Stuff ( )
      {
            super ( ) ;
      }

      Stuff ( int x )
      {
            this ( ) ;
      }
}
```

In the same constructor, no.
`super` or `this` has to be the first thing in a constructor.
If `super` is first, then `this` can't be first.
If `this` is first, then `super` can't be first.
They can not coexist in the same constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You call your another contructor with `this()` and in this constructor you call `super()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just place the call to `super()` in only one of the constructors:

```
public class Foo extends Bar 
{
   private int y;

   public Foo(int x)
   {
      this(x, 0);
   }

   public Foo(int x, int y)
   {
      super(x);
      this.y = y;
   }
}

public class Bar
{
   private int x;

   public Bar(int x)
   {
      this.x = x;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Call constructor overload in this class (below)
public Foo(){
   this("Some stuff");
}

// Call constructor overload in superclass.
public Foo(String stuff){
   super(stuff)
}
```

Comment: It's awfully short on the explanation though. [emory](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9660478/377270) and [hunter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9660529/377270) both provide guidance on how to write an excellent answer.

Comment: Except that it doesn't. It doesn't show whether or not you can call `super()` and `this()`in the same constructor. Not that any code sample could show that, you would have to compile it. Why the OP didn't just try it is a mystery.